# Refresh D3 generated table every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3.js table that is generated from a CSV file, and I'm trying to figure out how to get it to update the values either A) when the CSV is modified or B) every 10 seconds.

The issue I'm having is that I keep getting an error in the browser console that 'refresh' is undefined.

Can someone show my error? my setTimeout seems to not be working; it's probably something simple but I'm not super knowledgeable about javascript.

```
 d3.text("http://somesite/somefile.csv", function refresh(data) {

            var containerclear = d3.select("body").select("table").remove();

            var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

            var container = d3.select("body")
                .append("table")

                .selectAll("tr")
                    .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                    .append("tr")

                .selectAll("td")
                    .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                    .append("td")
                    .text(function(d) { return d; });

        });
        setTimeout(function() {
                    refresh(data);
                    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find your refresh function as its inside this function :

```
d3.text("http://somesite/somefile.csv", function refresh(data) {
```

Move this outside like so :

```
  function refresh(data) {

                var containerclear = d3.select("body").select("table").remove();

                var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

                var container = d3.select("body")
                    .append("table")

                    .selectAll("tr")
                        .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                        .append("tr")

                    .selectAll("td")
                        .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                        .append("td")
                        .text(function(d) { return d; });

            }
```

And call it here :

```
 d3.text("http://somesite/somefile.csv", function(data){ refresh(data)}); //using the somefile.csv
```

And here :

```
setTimeout(function() {
                    refresh(data); //using a different dataset
                    }, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm not quite sure I understand; on the third bit where the timeout function is created, refresh(data); is it calling the first function? I ask because I get an undefined error again, this time its for 'data'.

Comment: Oh wait, I think it's because I'm using setTimeout not setInterval. After changing the commands this worked perfectly. Thanks!